# Get the bitwise combined value of flag values from an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, bit-manipulation

I have an enum:

```
enum States {
    Empty = 0,
    NoData = 0x1,
    UnChecked = 0x2,
    Review = 0x4
}
```

I have loaded these into a multiselect control so I can select values into an array like:
`[0, 0x1, 0x2]`

How can I get the bitwise combined value (6 by the example) in typescript?

Comment: Just add them together (which raises the question: why 6?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to perform bitwise combinaison?

```js
const addition = [
  0x01,
  0x02,
  0x04,
].reduce((tmp, x) => tmp | x, 0);

console.log(`0x${addition.toString(16)}`);
```